# Why is no angular module found?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular

In my angulsr2 project under visual studio, I'm not able to compile typescript files after migrating angular2 from beta to rc.

I'm getting

> Build:Cannot find module '@angular2/platform/browser'.
>
> Build:Cannot find module '@angular2/router'.
>
> Build:Cannot find module '@angular2/http'.
>
> etc...

**Project Tree**

[image: Project Tree]

**Errors**

[image: Errors]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceRoot": "/app/ts",
    "module": "system",
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/app/js",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

** packages.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "AngularTest",
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
      "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",

      "systemjs": "0.19.27",
      "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
      "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
      "jquery": "2.1.4",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "^3.9.1",
      "del": "2.1.0"
    }
}
```

I'm not certain what's missed, I'm comparing against other project and I seem to have the same but something is obviously different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `@angular2`. It's either `@angular` or for older versions `angular2`. You need to fix your imports.

```
... from '@angular/platform/browser'.
... from '@angular/router'.
... from '@angular/http'.
```

Comment: What a silly mistake... I did a massive replace and didn't notice this. Thanks